# Django Channels direct messaging and server sent events

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Hello I am building a multiplayer poker game. So far I have built the poker portion where instances of players are created and a table is created then hands are stored in the player object and the board and pot and betting takes place in the table instance.

I’d like to create a multiplayer version where instead of taking inputs from the command line, a chat room like interface will take in betting and display hands and the board.

Functionality I need:

- output hand to one specific websocket
- input bet from one specific websocket and then output that bet to the next websocket and receive a bet and output to the next and so on
- output pot size and board and player balance to specific websocket

So far I have used the channels tutorial to build a basic chat app.

The issue I’m facing is that most of the tutorials  and content are tailored toward broadcasting messages to everyone.

Please help!